# Apple Push Notifications not arriving on iOS device from Microsoft Azure Notification Hub

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7, azure-notificationhub

I have followed-up the tutorial [Microsoft Azure Notification Hub for iOS apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/#comments) till the end and successfully registered device for push notifications. When I send a test notification from Debug option in Azure Classic Portal the Result shown with options Registration ID (XXXXXX12345), Platforms (apple) and Outcome says "The Notification was successfully sent to the Push Notification System" but my device is not receiving any Notifications. I have uploaded a valid `.p12` certificate into Azure Portal as well. I am using azuresdk-iOS-v1.2.4 framework with `iOS 9`. Please help me on it.

```
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:HUBLISTENACCESS notificationHubPath:HUBNAME];

[hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError* error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
    }
    else {

        [self MessageBox:@"Registration Status" message:@"Registered"];
    }
}];
```

Do I need to covert deviceToken into Hexadecimal? right now am passing deviceToken as it is what am getting in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method.

Comment: Make sure that, you have enabled "push" for the provision profiles you've build with. And if this is correct, double check, what's the build type? It should be a "release" type else you will not able to see a push. If both are great then wait for some time, in my case, sometime Apple takes 15 minutes to send a push.

Comment: @Hemang, thank you for your reply. My Provision and .p12 cert are correct as I have uploaded same into Parse for testing as well and am receiving notifications from Parse but not from Azure Notification hub. I was waiting from yesterday to get notofication.

Comment: Have you checked about "release" build?

Comment: If you are running from Xcode, make sure your Notification Hub is set up with a Sandbox certificate, or if your app is running from TestFlight or the App Store, make sure your Notification Hub has a Production certificate. Also try removing the app and reinstalling it on your device. Also check Apple's tech note https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html for more details. Finally, you probably know this, but Simulators cannot receive notifications.

Comment: @Hemang, can you elaborate more on this "Release" option. Are you talking about these following options? AppName-Edit Schema- Archive-Build Configuration set to Release only. Or
Targets-Build Settings-Build Active Architecture Only-Debug set to YES and Release set to NO

Comment: Yes, I was talking about, Build Configuration in Edit Scheme.

Comment: @EricHedstrom, Thank you for your reply. I selected Sandbox and uploaded development certificate only not Production certificate. I am running this app from Xcode only, not from TestFlight and Apple Store.

Comment: @Hemang, below are the current build settings... Please let me know where you want me to set "Release" from below schema options.... AppName-Edit Schema- Build -> There is no any option to set Release and Debug.
AppName-Edit Schema- Run -> Info-Build Configuration set to Debug.
AppName-Edit Schema- Archive -> Test-Info-Build Configuration set to Debug.
AppName-Edit Schema- Archive -> Profile-Info-Build Configuration set to Release.
AppName-Edit Schema- Analyze -> Build Configuration set to Debug.
AppName-Edit Schema- Archive -> Build Configuration set to Release.

Comment: I believe, you should update `AppName-Edit Schema- Run -> Info-Build Configuration set to Debug` change it to `Release`.

Comment: @Hemang, I tried by setting it to "Release" but no luck. Any other tools to debug where it got stuck?

Comment: @Hemang, One more question. Do I need to convert device token into Hexadecimal? right now I am passing token as it is what am getting in "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" method. 
I have updated my question with code snippet. Can you please look at once?

Comment: @GaneshGuturi, you have done it correctly. As long I can see that, you're passing the same datatype value  (`NSData`) in `SBNotificationHub`'s method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101213/discussion-between-ganesh-guturi-and-hemang).